# My method should return new instance of different classes. I do not understand how to use here generics in right way

Tags: java, generics, selenium-webdriver

I use switch statement with String method's argument in my method. And I need that each case block returns different 'new MyClass(driver)' with WebDriver in Constructor. My method looks like:

```
    public ???? clickOnReviewTab(String tabName){

    switch (tabName) {

        case "Treatment Reviews":
            tab("TREATMENT REVIEWS").click();
        return new ReviewsPage(driver);

        case "Videos & Guides":
            tab("VIDEOS & GUIDES").click();
        return new VideosPage(driver)'
    }

}
```

As I understood I have to use Generic there. Could you help how to write this method in a right way, and how to use it method in main Test class. Thanks.

Comment: Actually what you need is an interface or a parent class, not generics

Comment: I think It's better to use inheritance in your case

Comment: thank you, I resolved that using a parent class.

Comment: @Oleksii, You can also use an interface - please check below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the ReviewsPage and VideosPage have a common parent class/ or implement the same interface (i call it BaseView in the code) you simply can write (no need for generics here):

```
public BaseView clickOnReviewTab(String tabName){

    switch (tabName) {

    case "Treatment Reviews":
        tab("TREATMENT REVIEWS").click();
        return new ReviewsPage(driver);

    case "Videos & Guides":
        tab("VIDEOS & GUIDES").click();
        return new VideosPage(driver)'
    }
    return null; // or whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I resolved my issue with a parent class. But just in case whether I have to do if those classes would not have a parent class?

Comment: @Oleksii then you have to return `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do it this way

```
abstract class Page {
    public Page(Driver driver){...}
}

class ReviewsPage extends Page {...}

class VideosPage extends Page {...}

public Page clickOnReviewTab(String tabName) {...}
```